# How do I make react hookstate.js stop rerendering when using .set?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a state object already set in hookstate. In a particular file, I have the following calling it:

```
const druidPowers = useDruidPowersState(druidPowersState)

  useEffect(() => {
   Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/powers/druidpowers/levelone')
    .then((data) => {
        const powersData = data.data.druidpowers[0].powers.levelOne
        druidPowers.shapeshift.set(powersData.shapeshift)
        druidPowers.naturesBoon.set(powersData.naturesBoon)
    })
  }, [druidPowers.shapeshift, druidPowers.naturesBoon])

  druidPowers.shapeshift.powerUsage.set({
      powerUse: {
        hp: (characterHp, body, spirit) => {
          characterHp += (body + spirit)
        }
      }
    })
  
  console.log(druidPowers, 'druid powers')
```

The code inside the useEffect does what I intend no issues. It's when I add in the .set() outside of the useEffect that becomes the issue.
Console confirms this is updating it for me. However, it also confirms that it won't stop console.log()'ing it. I tried, just on random chance, to put a , [] in there like you would on a useEffect, but that didn't stop it, so just wondering if anyone knows why it keeps doing it.

Comment: Could you give a more detailed code snippet? What you gave lacks context. Are you using it in a `useEffect`?

Comment: There's some more that's related directly to it. The sets in my useEffect work fine. As you can see, the current issue code is not in a useEffect.

Comment: The set in useEffect will only run when druidPowers.shapeshift or druidPowers.naturesBoon changes. The console.log and the other set function might run many times, depending on your component. It's not uncommon when you put a console.log in a React component to see it output more frequently to the console than you expected. Generally it means your component is updating in some way you hadn't considered.

Comment: @KevinAshworth I'm not sure I understand that entirely. When I take out the .set() I tried to use outside the useEffect, there's no issues, and everything inside the useEffect happens, regardless. So that wasn't any worry.

Edit: Hit enter too early. I was going to say you're being generous in saying "you hadn't considered.". It's more like don't know, hence why I'm asking, haha.
So by altering the properties that were used in the useEffect in the first place, that's likely doing it? Spitballing based on what you said. Bigger question, I suppose. Will it matter that it's doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of Hookstate is here. State instances are refreshed on each rerender, so your effect is triggered on each rerender. Replace `[druidPowers.shapeshift, druidPowers.naturesBoon]` by `[]` and will stop running the effect. ES Lint complaints can be suppressed for this line.

Also, please see related ticket: https://github.com/avkonst/hookstate/issues/140

Comment: Know it's delayed, but tyvm for that.